# What options for indexing Exchange mailboxes with SharePoint?

Tags: search, crawling, exchange-server

What options are recommended for indexing Exchange mailboxes with SharePoint?

So far I have found the following:

- I found [one article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointsearch/thread/be42655d-696b-4418-b32b-08b5781b1571), which mentions that you can add `http://fqdn/exchange` and/or `http://fqdn/exchange/user_alias` as a content source, but as I have very limited expierence with Exchange I have no idea what those URI's are for and what it would be indexing
- I found a bunch of [third](http://sharepointsearch.com/Pages/product.aspx?PID=38&VID=BA-Insight) [party](http://www.ba-insight.net/Products/Connectors/Exchange/Pages/Exchange-Mailboxes.aspx) [options](http://sharepointworks.com/pages/escexchange.aspx) which seem promising - so any feedback on them would be beneficial
- The third option I found is that Exchange supports Journaling which can be used to send mail to SharePoint which I can then search using built in SharePoint features? This seems to be a very interesting option, from a SharePoint perspective, as it means I can leverage existing SharePoint skills and features (like the security model) to get fine grained control. However I am not sure what the con's to this option are?

Comment: The version of SharePoint you are using may be helpful here.

Comment: 2010 - is there any other version that should be spoken about ;)

Comment: Another option: http://exchangebcs.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is technically possible, but further investigation points to SharePoint not being the correct interface for this.

Looking at the information I found previously, some additional information...

> You can add `http://fqdn/exchange` and/or `http://fqdn/exchange/user_alias` as a content source

This is refering to using the out of the box crawl tools to search the OWA interface. This is generally a bad idea because the content of the mail will be available to everyone who can use that search. This also has the downside of needing to be setup per mailbox.

> Third party options

These are an option, in particular the BA Insight one which maintain security per user.

> Exchange supports Journaling which can be used to send mail to SharePoint

This is also a good option, but suffers from the same issue as indexing OWA - everyone who can search can see all the emails.

If we reverse the issue and look at the goals of searching mail better suited solutions appear:

- Users searching their own mail: Windows Desktop Search provides this.
- Compliance and legal searching: The built in search feature in Exchange provides this.
- Searching archives: Most archive solutions for Exchange provide this feature already.
- Surfacing email/calendars/contacts in SharePoint (i.e. SharePoint as a single UI): SharePoint has web parts that do this, without adding the content to the search catalog