# Can Exchange connector for SharePoint 2013 index users emails?

Tags: 2013, search

Can Exchange connector for SharePoint 2013 index users emails? nothing mentioned in MSDN, it is all about public folders. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591608(v=office.15).aspx

if it is able to crawl emails, please provide me with some references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not. There are two Exchange scenarios.

1. Crawl Exchange Public Folders
2. Exchange eDiscovery - This uses the eDiscovery center to connect to
   exchange and search (not crawl) specific users. I believe this is
   actually a federated search as it is probably connecting to the
   Exchange Search Service. This feature is only available in the
   eDiscovery Center.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly Public Folders are used to have a common place for Employees to share their Critical Data. Like- Sales info,Pay Slip generation, Common Documents etc

Read the below technet to understand the public folder concept:

[Understanding Public Folders](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397221(v=exchg.141).aspx)
[Exchange 2013 – Public Folders – Architecture](http://careexchange.in/exchange-2013-public-folders-architecture-part-1/)

and also read this one
[What options for indexing Exchange mailboxes with SharePoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7731/what-options-for-indexing-exchange-mailboxes-with-sharepoint)